# How to automatically detect username when setting file path for icon

Tags: command-line, bash

Im creating a desktop shortcut. I've been playing around with some of the lines and one thing I'm currently stuck at is automatically detecting username for a file path for an icon.

This code works currently but with manual username input in the line.
`Icon=/home/myusername/Desktop/Icons/test_icon.png`

What I'm trying to find out is
`Icon=/home/**automaticallydetectusername**/Desktop/Icons/test_icon.png`

Comment: I tried this earlier but it didn't work ):

Comment: The only supported way I know of is to place the icons in one of the user-specific default icon search directories ex. `~/.local/share/icons` - see [freedesktop icon theme specification: Directory Layout](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/latest/ar01s03.html). At a pinch, I suppose you could modify `XDG_DATA_DIRS` to include your custom location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.desktop` files are hardcoded. They do not support bash expansions or variables.

The approach to go about this here is to specify the icon by its file name without extension in the `.desktop` file, as in:

```
Icon=myicon
```

Then have the icon, customized for the user, installed in `~/.local/share/icons` or `~/.icons`, e.g  `~/.local/share/icons.png`.

An icon file installed in these user configuration directories will take precedence over systemwide installed icons with the same file name (`/usr/local/share/icons`, or `/usr/share/icons` for applications installed using the package management system).

Comment: Got it, thank you for the explanation

Comment: Please consider accepting the question if it answered your issue.